# React-tinder-card library Cards are not stacking properly one on top of the other?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, swipe

I am trying to emulate the notorious Tinder swipe card UI in my project and have found and used react-tinder-card to implement swiping cards, however, these cards are stacked on top of each other but not in the right way (difficult to explain but image below):

[image]

As you can see the bottom of this card is the top of the next card, but I want the next card to be underneath the top card like it is on the demo of the library that I followed to produce this.

[image]

https://github.com/3DJakob/react-tinder-card-demo

I followed the Simple example and here is my code:

```
export const SwipeCard = () => {

    //array of users fetched for a user.
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [lastDirection, setLastDirection] = useState()
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

    //gets the users and sets loading to false on render.
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers().then(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        });
    }, []);

    const swiped = (direction, nameToDelete) => {
        console.log('removing: ' + nameToDelete)
        setLastDirection(direction)
    }

    const outOfFrame = (firstName) => {
        console.log(firstName + ' left the screen!')
    }

    const getUsers = async () => {
        const userId = 7;
        const response = await UserService.getUsers(userId)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    users[i] = data[i];
                }
            });
    }

    if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div/>
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div id='tinderCards'>
            {users.map((user) =>
                <TinderCard className='swipeCard' key={user.firstName} onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, user.firstName)} onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(user.firstName)}>
                    <div className='card'>
                        <img id='profileImg' src={config.URL + '/users/' + user.userID + '/image/download'} />
                        <h2>{user.firstName} {user.lastName}</h2>
                        <h3>Bio: {user.bio}</h3>
                    </div>
                </TinderCard>
            )}
        </div>
            {lastDirection ? <h2 className='text'>You swiped {lastDirection}</h2> : <h2 className='text' />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to wrap these:

```html
<div class="relative"> 
    asdasd
    <div class="absolute"> 
        asdasdasd
    </div>
</div>
```